# How to buffer and process chunked data before sending headers in IIS7 Native Module

Tags: c++, iis-7

So I've been working on porting an IIS6 ISAPI module to IIS7. One problem that I have is that I need to be able to parse and process responses, and then change/delete/add some HTTP headers based on the content. I got this working fine for most content, but it appears to break down when chunked encoding is being used on the response body.

It looks like CHttpModule::OnSendResponse is being called once for each chunk. I've been able to determine when a chunked response is being sent, and to buffer the data until all of the chunks have been passed in, and set the entity count to 0 to prevent it from sending that data out, but after the first OnSendResponse is called the headers are sent to the client already, so I'm not able to modify them later after I've already processed the chunked data.

I realize that doing this is going to eliminate the benefits of the chunked encoding, but in this case it is necessary.

The only example code I can find for IIS Native Modules are very simplistic and don't demonstrate performing any filtering of response data. Any tips or links on this would be great.

**Edit:** Okay, I found IHttpResponse::SuppressHeaders, which will prevent the headers from being sent after the first OnSendResponse. However, now it will not send the headers at all. So what I did was when it's a chunked response I set it to suppress headers, and then later after I process the response, I check to see if the headers were suppressed, and if they were I read all of the headers from raw response structure (HTTP_RESPONSE), and insert them at the beginning of the response entity chunks myself. This seems to work okay so far.

Still open to other ideas if anybody has any better option.

Comment: For future head-scratchers, one issue of note on IIS 7.5 (and possibly other versions):  after suppressing headers during chunked responses, IIS no longer populated any custom headers defined in the web.config files.  I had to manually add them in, using the IAppHostAdminManager and related functions.  The path to said headers is 'system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders'

Comment: Update to my previous comment:  for some reason, I need to do a project clean and rebuild any time I change the DWORD notification flags that get fed into the SetRequestNotifications method.  Then the missing headers suddenly become available.  If I change the DWORDs without doing a full clean/rebuild, the headers go missing again.  Sometimes.  This is on VS Pro 2013.  Good times!